# Configure Sendmail as Secondary/Anonymous SMTP Solution

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail

I have a scenario where I want to allow my clients a secondary SMTP service, e.g. they are hosted on SERVER1 and using the same server as a primary mail server, Now I want to allow them to use the Secondary mail server SERVER2.

On SERVER1 they connect through Mail clients using authentication, while on SERVER2 I want to allow them to send emails without authentication, I will add SERVER2 IP entry in their domain's SPF too.

I need help regarding setting Sendmail's relay to allow them to send emails, Right now it's not connecting to the SERVER2 if I try from Outlook.

I have set Open Relay in Sendmail's access file as below already.

```
*.*       RELAY
```

But somehow it's not working.

P.S. For test purposes, I have disabled the firewalls already!

Thanks for help in advance.